# JSF integrate with SpringBoot1.5

Tags: spring-boot, jsf

When I integrate JSF (myface) with SpringBoot1.5

Which listener should I use at web.xml , what is the difference between them, see below?

org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Answer (score 0):

You should use ContextLoaderListener with spring-boot.

```
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
```

as suggested [in this article](https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot)

To find the differences refer below links.

[org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)

[org/apache/myfaces/webapp/StartupServletContextListener.](https://myfaces.apache.org/core22/myfaces-impl/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/webapp/StartupServletContextListener.html)

Comment: thanks. or could i use both? or i need to kick out org/apache/myfaces/webapp/StartupServletContextListener.?

Comment: it depends on your purpose..spring context listener will serve your purpose so go for it.

Comment: In this case, do I still need use web.xml to register listener? Should I configure all listeners with java Config?